# Convolution of positive and negative functions?

Tags: signal, convolution

I am trying to do convolution for the function below

[image]

The correct solution is as follows:
[image]

I tried solving the problem, below is my attempt:
[image]
[image]

Can you please advise me where is my mistake?

Comment: This is a mathematics question, not EE.

Comment: @Brian Drummond this topic is crucial for signals and systems course. Btw if all topics that involve mathematical calculations are considered part of math you will be left with very few subjects in EE. Right?